# How OpenGL set gl_ClipPlane[]?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Legacy GLSL code allow to access `gl_ClipPlane[]` variable. How that variable is set ? For example calling `glTranslatef` or `glLoadMatrix` updates other built-in variable - `gl_ModelViewMatrix`.

Comment: [`glClipPlane`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml)

Comment: What if the ```glClipPlane``` is not called ? Does the ```glClipPlane[]``` has the default value ?

Comment: [`glClipPlane`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml): *"All clipping planes are initially defined as (0, 0, 0, 0) in eye coordinates and are disabled."*